# Running on linked list inside of a linked list in C

Tags: c, linked-list

suppose I have a struct that I use as a linked list (one sided), lets say

```
struct s1
{
   char *word;
   struct s1 *next;
};
```

Now I make another struct that should also be a linked list, that has the first one:

```
struct s2
{
    int b;
    struct s1 *firstfroms1;
    struct s2 *next;
}
```

In my program, I want to run on s2, but in it I want to run on all of the elements that firstfroms1 leads to. For example, if a list from s2 end after 2 times, and the first one has 4 elements from s1, I want to run on these four.

Problem is, when I write list->firstfroms1->word ,I can access only to the first one of s1. How can I move that "index" until I reach NULL in s1?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Loop over the list of `s2`, if the current node contains a list of `s1` structures (`firstfroms1` is non-null) then loop over them before continuing. So, loop within a loop.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this using standard linked list semantincs, where each list element is capable of giving you the next element or null. When you are "side branching" to the s1 list, those list elements have no clue that they belong to s2 and they would not know what to do once the end of the list is reached.

The knowledge that you have two nested lists is only available in s2 and hence you can only iterate over s2.

However, then you must return s2 elements. You will need an extra dereference operation to obtain the current s1 element from the current s2 element something like `*(some_S2.firstFromS1)` assuming you update firstFromS1 as you iterate.